# Increase test class coverage

Tags: unit-test, class, scheduled-apex, code-coverage

I create scheduled apex and create test class but i only get 71% code coverage even though i already create test contact that meet the query. When i try to command on the query i got 100% code coverage with same test class.

Here is the first apex class (71%)

```
global class DepostiInvoiceAutomation implements Schedulable
{
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
{  
    Date dt = Date.newInstance(2016,12,1);

    List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    List<Deposit_Invoice__c> depositToCreate = new List<Deposit_Invoice__c>();
    List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>();
    listContact= [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=true AND Deposit_Received__c = true AND Next_Deposit_Generate_Date__c!= null 
                  AND Next_Deposit_Generate_Date__c<=:system.today() AND CreatedDate>=:dt AND Account.Are_All_Opportunities_Closed__c=false 
                  AND Account.Sign_Up__c=true LIMIT 100];

    for(Contact con : listContact){
        con.Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c = false;
        contactToUpdate.add(con);
        Deposit_Invoice__c dep = new Deposit_Invoice__c(Contact__c=con.id,Amount__c=250000);
        depositToCreate.add(dep);
    }
    update contactToUpdate;
    insert depositToCreate;
}
}
```

Here is the updated code (100%) after i command "Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=TRUE". **Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c is checkbox field that have default value true**

```
global class DepostiInvoiceAutomation implements Schedulable
{
global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) 
{  
    Date dt = Date.newInstance(2016,12,1);

    List<Contact> contactToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
    List<Deposit_Invoice__c> depositToCreate = new List<Deposit_Invoice__c>();
    List<Contact> listContact = new List<Contact>();
    listContact= [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE /*Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=true AND*/ Deposit_Received__c = true AND Next_Deposit_Generate_Date__c!= null 
                  AND Next_Deposit_Generate_Date__c<=:system.today() AND CreatedDate>=:dt AND Account.Are_All_Opportunities_Closed__c=false 
                  AND Account.Sign_Up__c=true LIMIT 100];

    for(Contact con : listContact){
        con.Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c = false;
        contactToUpdate.add(con);
        Deposit_Invoice__c dep = new Deposit_Invoice__c(Contact__c=con.id,Amount__c=250000);
        depositToCreate.add(dep);
    }
    update contactToUpdate;
    insert depositToCreate;
}
}
```

Here is the test class

```
@isTest
private class TestDepositInvoiceAutomation{

static testMethod void automateDeposit1()
{
    Datetime createDate = Datetime.now().addDays(-29);
    Account acc = new Account(Name='test acc',Sign_Up_Timestamp__c=system.today());
    insert acc;
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName='test con',AccountId=acc.id,Deposit_Received_Date__c=system.today().addDays(-100),Deposit_Received__c=true,
                              Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=true);
    insert con;
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='test opp', AccountId=acc.id,StageName='Invoiced',CloseDate = system.today());
    insert opp;
    con.Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=false;
    update con;
    Deposit_Invoice__c dep = new Deposit_Invoice__c(Contact__c=con.id,Amount__c = 250000);
    insert dep;

    System.schedule('testDepostiInvoiceAutomation', '0 31 13 * * ?', new DepostiInvoiceAutomation());

}
}
```

**Is there something i miss?**

Comment: It looks like Next_Deposit_Generate_Date__c should be set to a specific value (Date.today). Make sure you have all the fields you need.

Comment: Please include code as text, not images.

Comment: It means field Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c is not correctly setup in test class and query return zero row. That's why code (Inside for loop) is marked in red

Comment: What I have identified is first you are inserting a contact with Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c= TRUE. Then after inserting Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c=FALSE after opportunity creation. Your query is looking Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c= TRUE that is not available in data. The best approach is to use system.assert to verify your result in test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a contact with `Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c= true` and then after inserting `opportunity` you are updating the `con.Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c= false` so the value of `Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c` will be `false`.

In your query you are trying to select `Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c = true` but you have updated the `Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c = false`, you will not be getting any records for this condition because of that the for loop is not executing. 
When you comment `Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c` you will get records and the for loop gets executed.

Comment: it make it 100% code coverage, i do that because i think we need to create scenario exactly like the class thats why i create "Is_Deposit_Not_Generated__c = false".

Comment: Congrats you have executed every line and tested nothing